# Is there an easy way to ignore duplicates with django models unique=TRUE?

Tags: python, sql, django

```
class Reddit_Submission(models.Model):
    submission_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    submission_time_stamp = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    submission_title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    submission_score = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    submission_author = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    submission_url = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

I have the above code sample from my Model within my django application. My question is, Is there a easy way to ignore a "Example = model.save()" if something is duplicated within the database already?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends which of the above fields you wanted them to be unique. After deciding the fields that should be unique and sated them as 'unique=True' on your model, you can handle request on your view on such a way:

```
def create(self, request):
     

    try:
        serializer = Reddit_Submission_Serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    
    except:
        return Response(data={'message': "Duplicate field detected"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to just catch integrity error and check if there is a unique constraint message and ignore it. If not, just raise again:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

try:
    model.save()
except IntegrityError as e:
    if 'UNIQUE constraint' in str(e):
        pass
    raise
```